# Как хранить статистику о пользователе в БД?

Tags: база-данных

Всем привет! Есть таблица пользователей, в которой хранится вся инфа о пользователе. Задача - создать статистику по месяцам, т.е. сколько каких-то действий пользователь сделал за конкретный месяц. Как это сделать? Для каждого месяца создавать отдельную таблицу и в нее записывать действия пользователей? Может есть какие-то другие способы?

Comment: что такое "действие пользователя" , если можно класифицировать действия- достаточно одной таблицы: дата, пользователь, действие

Comment: Пользователь заливает файлы или удаляет их со своего хранилища...

Comment: т.е. 2 действия - 1 таблица id,id_пользователя, дата, id_действия (0-залить, 1-удалить) можно ещё и имя файла и его размер...  Анализировать такую таб. очень просто

Comment: Хммм. Эти все поля мне придется хранить ради того, чтобы потом вытащить их количество например за июль? Не странно ли?

Comment: таблица с 4 интовскими полями (дата почти интовское) - это ниочём для базы. если пугают объёмы данных - можно удалять старые данные. это намного проще чем в ответе МАХОРКА.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таблице, у каждого пользователя создаются 2 поля-счетчика. Раз в месяц, из планировщика задач запускается скрипт, который переносит числа в полях в таблицу со статистикой, записывая туда идентификатор пользователя, номер месяца, и 2 параметра. После этого поля-счетчики в таблице с пользователями - обнуляются.

Comment: зачем такой гемор?

Comment: @Вадим чтобы хранить статистику.

Comment: А выборка по периодам запрещена?

Comment: @TristernespykTresteet нет